# Contains or in filtering using DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have a simple Blog app, which contains models `Entry` with ManyToManyField, called tags
**MODELS**

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Entry(models.Model):
    ...
    tags = models.ManyToManyFiled(Tag)
    ...
```

I also have a filter class `django_filters.rest_framework.FilterSet`, which should be able to filter entries which contain **the only** tags that were passed to request or the **tags + others**.

---

How do I implement FilterSet class fields to be able to filter this way as I pass to request **id**s of tags?

Answer (score 2):

Implement your viewset like this with the filter_backends and filter_fields

```
class EntryList(generics.ListAPIView):
   queryset = Entry.objects.all()
   serializer_class = EntrySerializer
   filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
   filter_fields = ('tags',')
```

Then your URL will be similar to this if you want to filter by the URL parameters:

example.com/api/entry?tag=mytag

Comment: I meant that I could pass tags' ids and get Entries with these tags exactly or with these tags + extra. That would be 2 different filters, I suppose

Comment: In this case you will need to override the get_queryset method in your views and filter the queryset manually with the values that you need.
Have a look at this link:  http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-the-current-user

Comment: There is no way to do this in FilterSet class? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Maybe. Try to use filter_fields = ('tags_id',') but I think in your case you will need a special get_queryset